# is "child" without "a" correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

He was still child enough to run along with the group.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: 'He was still man enough to admit his mistakes' is grammatically correct.  So, it you know for sure that 'child enough' is permissible in the same way as 'man enough',  then (maybe?) you can match the conditions and affirm that it can go without an article.

Comment: He was still child enough to run along with the group.= He was still **enough of a child** *in order* to run along with the group. -> He was still **childlike enough**  in order (or to be allowed) to run along with the group.

Answer (score 1):

> He was still child enough to run along with the group.

It is an idiom.

*I was fool enough to dive into the water.*

*He was hero enough to save the drowning kitten.*

It is correct because "child" acts as an adjective here.

Compare:

*He was still young enough to run along with the group.*

Comment: Yes, it's convenient to treat it like an adjective. If you insisted on respecting its nounhood, you'd hafta say _enough of a child_ instead of _child enough_. Two more meaningless chunks of syntactic machinery.